# SQL Server 2008 Auditing - reports

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, auditing

Other than using SQL statement like 
SELECT * FROM fn_get_audit_file('C:\SQLSvrAuditing*', default, default), are there good reporting available for SQL Server auditing? Even if there are useful query templates, it will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no elegant solution for reading *.sqlaudit files.

One option is to use the fn_get_audit_file function, like you said. You can use the exact column list, and add a WHERE condition to narrow down the results. E.g.

```
WHERE action_id IN ( 'LGIF' , '%AU%', 'SL', 'IN', 'DR',  )
```

Another option is to use the Log File Viewer utility in SQL Server Management Studio.

[image]

[image]